# How to keep text selection visible in a text area even though not focused

Tags: reactjs, textarea, selection, visible

How to keep the selection visible in a text area when it lost focus in React/JS.

Back then when I learned JavaFX it has text area component which always showing the selection of its text even not in focus state. Only its color was blue (highlight) when focus and grey when it's not.

Comment: not possible for native, browser input - build custom field/editing component

Comment: all right then thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I might have done something like this, maybe it could help or give you an idea

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

    this.handleOnExit = this.handleOnExit.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleOnExit(e) {
  const node = this.myRef.current;
  node.select();
}

handleClick() {
  const node = this.myRef.current;
  node.select();
  console.log(this.myRef);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input ref={this.myRef} type="text" onBlur={this.handleOnExit} value="aaaa" />
      <input type="text" value="bbbb" />
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Click</button>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}> btn-2</button>
    </div>
  )};
}
```